# An error while trying to retrieve and decrypt login in Firefox

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on programm on VB.net to retrieve data from Firefox browser. I have an error while trying to use "PK11SDR_Decrypt" method from nss3.lib. "PK11SDR_Decrypt" returns -1. I don't have master password. I think that the problem in Ctypes/marshalling/base64 decoding. This is the code of function.

```
Public Function DecryptFF(ByVal str As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tSecDec As New TSECItem
    Dim e As Integer
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(str)
    Dim hi2 As Integer = NSSBase64_DecodeBuffer(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, sb, sb.Length)
    Dim item As TSECItem = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(New IntPtr(hi2), GetType(TSECItem)), TSECItem)
    e = PK11SDR_Decrypt(item, tSecDec, 0)
    If e = 0 Then
        If tSecDec.SECItemLen <> 0 Then
            Dim mozDecryptedData = New Byte(tSecDec.SECItemLen - 1) {}
            Marshal.Copy(New IntPtr(tSecDec.SECItemData), mozDecryptedData, 0, tSecDec.SECItemLen)
            Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mozDecryptedData)
        End If
    End If
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

And other code part.

```
Public NSS3 As IntPtr
Public hModuleList As New List(Of IntPtr)

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure TSECItem
    Public SECItemType As Integer
    Public SECItemData As Integer
    Public SECItemLen As Integer
End Structure

Public Function NSS_Init(ByVal configdir As String) As Long
    Dim PathM = FindFirefoxInstallationPath()
    hModuleList.Add(LoadLibrary(PathM & "\msvcp140.dll"))
    hModuleList.Add(LoadLibrary(PathM & "\mozglue.dll"))
    hModuleList.Add(LoadLibrary(PathM & "\mozavutils.dll"))
    NSS3 = LoadLibrary(PathM & "\nss3.dll")
    hModuleList.Add(NSS3)
    Return CreateAPI(Of DLLFunctionDelegate)(NSS3, "NSS_Init")(configdir)
End Function

Public Function CreateAPI(Of T)(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal method As String) As T 'Simple overload to avoid loading the same library every time
    Return DirectCast(DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GetProcAddress(hModule, method), GetType(T)), Object), T)
End Function

Public Function NSSBase64_DecodeBuffer(ByVal arenaOpt As IntPtr, ByVal outItemOpt As IntPtr, ByVal inStr As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal inLen As Integer) As Integer
    Dim pProc As IntPtr = GetProcAddress(NSS3, "NSSBase64_DecodeBuffer")
    Dim dll As DLLFunctionDelegate4 = DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, GetType(DLLFunctionDelegate4)), DLLFunctionDelegate4)
    Return dll(arenaOpt, outItemOpt, inStr, inLen)
End Function

Public Function PK11SDR_Decrypt(ByRef data As TSECItem, ByRef result As TSECItem, ByVal cx As Integer) As Integer
    Dim pProc As IntPtr = GetProcAddress(NSS3, "PK11SDR_Decrypt")
    Dim dll As DLLFunctionDelegate5 = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, GetType(DLLFunctionDelegate5)), DLLFunctionDelegate5)
    Return dll(data, result, cx)
End Function

<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Delegate Function DLLFunctionDelegate5(ByRef data As TSECItem, ByRef result As TSECItem, ByVal cx As Integer) As Integer
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Delegate Function DLLFunctionDelegate6() As Long

Public Function NSS_Shutdown() As Long
    Return CreateAPI(Of DLLFunctionDelegate6)(NSS3, "NSS_Shutdown")()
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Shared Function LoadLibrary(ByVal dllFilePath As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="FreeLibrary")>
Public Shared Function FreeLibrary(ByVal hModule As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True)>
Public Shared Function GetProcAddress(ByVal hModule As IntPtr, ByVal procName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

DecryptFF get as argument the encrypted login fron logins.json file. Here is the part of code

```
Dim JSONRegex As New Regex("\""(hostname|encryptedPassword|encryptedUsername)"":""(.*?)""")
Dim mozMC = JSONRegex.Matches(Logins)
For I = 0 To mozMC.Count - 1 Step 3
Dim host = mozMC(I).Groups(2).Value
Dim usr = mozMC(I + 1).Groups(2).Value
Dim pas = mozMC(I + 2).Groups(2).Value
Account = (DecryptFF(usr))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please get rid of On Error Resume Next. Use Try...Catch...Finally....End Try to handle exceptions.